# Google Fi on TMobile Hotspot in Turkey

Tags: turkey, internet, roaming

I'm in Turkey. I put an activated Google Fi data-only SIM in my TMOHS1 TMobile hotspot--the hotspot looks like it's working as expected but it has no internet connection. The error I see from the hotspot dashboard is "Unable to connect to T-Mobile network". I also configured the APN to be "h2g2", for there to be "None" for Authentication, and IP Type "IPv4v6". How do I troubleshoot this? I'm under the impression that this configuration (Google Fi SIM in a TMobile hotspot) should work while I'm abroad. Thanks for the help!

Comment: While this question fits on Travel Stack Exchange, I guess you might get better help on a site that covers phones or hotspots.

Comment: From what I read here (just a cursory glance): https://support.google.com/fi/answer/6157794 - there may be several issues. First - what's your plan? With "simply unlimited" you're out of luck, "flexible" you might soon be out of money. Second -  "Important: In "Manage Plan,"  you must turn on the desired International Features for your services to work."